# sqlalchemy `subquery` and `json_agg` is not supposed to work well

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy version: `1.4.0`

This is the postgres query that I would like to run.

```sql
SELECT 
    "table_a".id,
    "table_a".body,
    "table_a".created_at,
    "table_a".archived_at,
    "user".full_name,
    (
        SELECT json_agg(items_alias_b)
        FROM (
            SELECT items_alias_a.id, items_alias_a.type, items_alias_a.filename, items_alias_a.s3_original_key
            FROM items items_alias_a
            WHERE items_alias_a.status = 'completed'::itemsstatusenum
                AND items_alias_a.id = ANY("table_a".item_ids)
        ) items_alias_b
    ) AS "items"
FROM "table_a"
JOIN "user" ON "user".id = "table_a".created_by
WHERE "table_a".other_id = 'XXXXXXXX'
ORDER BY "table_a".id DESC
```

I am trying to do this in sqlalchemy but not sure how to do this.
If anyone could help this, that would be great.

```py
class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_a"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    other_id = Column(
        String,
        ForeignKey("other.id", use_alter=True, ondelete="CASCADE"),
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    body = Column(Text, index=True)
    item_ids = Column(ARRAY(String))
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), server_default=func.now())
    created_by = Column(
        BigInteger,
        ForeignKey(User.id, ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False,
    )
    archived_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), nullable=True)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String, nullable=False)


items_subquery = db_session.query(
    Model.Item.id,
    Model.Item.type,
    Model.Item.name,
).filter(
    Model.Item.status == Model.ItemStatusEnum.completed,
    Model.Item.id == func.any(Model.TableA.items_ids),
).subquery()

query = (
    db_session.query(
        Model.TableA.id,
        Model.TableA.body,
        Model.TableA.created_at,
        Model.TableA.archived_at,
        Model.User.full_name.label("full_name"),
        func.json_agg(items_subquery).label("items"),
    )
    .join(
        Model.User,
        Model.User.id == Model.TableA.created_by,
    )
    .filter(
        Model.TableA.other_id == other_id,
    )
    .order_by(Model.TableA.id.desc())
)
messages = query.all()
```

I am getting the following logs when sqlalchemy is running.
This query is a little bit different than I expected. What should I do?

```
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery must return only one column

SELECT 
  table_a.id AS table_a_id, 
  table_a.body AS table_a_body, 
  table_a.created_at AS table_a_created_at, 
  table_a.archived_at AS table_a_archived_at, 
  "user".full_name AS full_name, 
  (
    SELECT 
      json_agg(
        (
          SELECT 
            item.id, 
            item.type, 
            item.name
          FROM 
            item, 
            table_a 
          WHERE 
            item.status = %(status_1) s 
            AND item.id = any(table_a.item_ids)
        )
      ) AS json_agg_1
  ) AS item 
FROM 
  table_a 
  JOIN "user" ON "user".id = table_a.created_by 
WHERE 
  table_a.other_id = %(other_id_1)
ORDER BY 
  table_a.id DESC
```

I was trying to get the right sqlalchemy code from postgres query but it didn't work as I have shared in the above.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post while trying to fix the same issue as you. After a long struggle I was able to get to know what exactly is going on and find the solution. It seems like you cannot pass the subquery variable directly into the select clause. So `func.json_agg(subquery)` will try to compile to something like that: `json_agg((SELECT ...))` which is not allowed in postgres.

What you need to do is to explicitly tell sqlalchemy, that you want to use the values instead of the query itself. What worked for me was calling `table_valued` method of the subquery, so the target code will look like this: `func.json_agg(subquery.table_valued())`

Hope it will work for you too.

PS This was my first time stumbling upon an issue which was younger than one month.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).